# ld: entry point (start) undefined. Usually in crt1.o for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc, osx-yosemite

I've written a simple hello world function for my terminal to compile and I keep getting

```
    587216304:EECS280 jacobmyers$ g++ hello.cpp -o hell
    ld: entry point (start) undefined.  Usually in crt1.o for architecture x86_64
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am using gcc version 4.9.2, And I can't find anything online that will fix this for me. I am pretty sure it has something to do with the I/O of the compilation.

also, here's the code to prove I can write a simple hello world function, should be good haha

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;


    int main()
    {
        cout<<"hello world";

    return  0;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: probably because of  `-o hell`. joke apart, do you have a `main` in your program? does your example you posted compile and link?

Comment: Your development environment is broken (you may re-install it)

Comment: how would i reinstall it?

Comment: It depends on your operating system.

Comment: i'm using OSX Yosemite, Version 10.10

Comment: What is the output of `g++ -v -Wall -Wextra hello.cpp -o hello`? If it's long try putting it in a pastebin.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/HeJPS1xk

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, says `for architecture x86_64`.
Try compiling with `-m32`: `g++ hello.cpp -o hello -m32`.

Also, I noted you use GCC 4.9.2. I compiled the same exact code (just copy-paste) using GCC 4.9.1 and it compiled and executed perfectly.

UPDATE:
Stumbled on this: [OSX-GCC-Installer](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/)
Uninstall the current GCC and download [the installer](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/releases/download/v0.3/GCC-10.7-v0.3.zip) and install it! Try it with that one, I've used it myself and it's good.

Comment: could you please tell me what your development environment is? (OS,Hardware,etc...)

Comment: OSX Yosemite, Version 10.10

Comment: Yeah, using OSX Yosemite myself, with GCC 4.9.1. You are using Apple's Xcode command line tools which include GCC, right?

Comment: Yea, i have tried installing and reinstalling it multiple times

Comment: Honestly, computers are awesome, but sometimes a pain in the neck. I have no idea further than what I've already suggested.

Comment: It says the installer only works for snow leopard (10.6)

Comment: Sorry, mixed the URLs, should work now. If you're downloading from Github, click the one that says Snow Leapard, the author of the software mixed the 2 up! Better yet, just click the second link in my post.